# Angular app, but protractor finds Angular in in some cases but not others

Tags: angularjs, angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have a Protractor test that works in Chrome, and when I added multicapabilities to the config file to cover Chrome and Firefox, several FIrefox attempts returned "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping."

I'm also getting this message for a page in Chrome that our developers have said IS in Angular.

Another test of an Angular page works as I go through entering information to go through account creation, but when the test tries to click Terms of Service, it results in that message right after the Selenium Server starts, even with  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); in the code. With that whole section commented out, it passes again consistently.
This is the code for that test, stripped of some other things in the attempt to debug:

```
describe('Profile Sign up with email', function() {  

it('should load profile signup page', function() {

browser.get('https://the_url_i_need.com');
});

it('should select Sign Up', function() {
element(by.css('label.ng-isolate-scope:nth-child(4) > span:nth-                       child(1)')).click();
});

it ('should make sure email address is the selected form of sign up',                         function() {
element(by.id('Radio1')).click();
});

browser.sleep(7000);
element(by.linkText('Terms of Service')).click();
});
```

Now, if "element(by.linkText('Terms of Service')).click();" is commented out, the test is fine; whether or not I have "browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);" or the lengthy sleep before it seems irrelevant. If the Terms of service link click is included, then the test returns the error above.

Since this is happening in multiple tests, how can I stabilize them in this regard?

Comment: Can you please post your configs/code, so we can see what you tried so far? And can you improve the readability of your question?

Comment: If that's not sufficient, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs, because you want to execute the click on that link before you have loaded an URL, because you don't execute it in an `it(...)` function.

Try following please:

```
describe('Profile Sign up with email', function() {  

    ...

    it ('should click successfully on Terms of Service', function() {
        browser.sleep(7000);
        element(by.linkText('Terms of Service')).click();
    });
});
```